# Brainwashed or sleeper agents

Tags: phantom-doctrine

As you can see in the following screenshot, the agent for hire has no perks.

Is it possible that he is a sleeper agent or could be any danger to my team?

Per what I have read around, those sleeper agents or brainwhased agents aways have a hidden perk that shows when they are "danger".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You'd see a "hidden perk", which could be revealed to be anything from aptitude for a certain type of work (increased XP or faster work), talent for certain tactics (reduced training time and cost for that particular type of training once it's unlocked), or, yes, "sleeper agent".

If he has no perks at all in the list he's not a danger, he's just boring.